# Problem with GRPC generating client and server code on Windows 10 after installing with VCPKG

Tags: c++, windows-10, grpc, vcpkg

I am having problems generating client and server code for a GRPC service. I'm adapting the instructions at [grpc.io](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/).

There is a single protobuf file `test_interface.proto` defining my service and I've tried to build it with both of the following commands, run in the same path as this file:

```
protoc -I . --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="C:\vcpkg\packages\grpc_x64-windows\tools\grpc\grpc_cpp_plugin" ./test_interface.proto
```

```
protoc -I . --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin ./test_interface.proto
```

Both of which result in the error:

```
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm on Windows 10 and installed grpc v1.33.1 using vcpkg. This installs the development dependencies, but does not add their binaries to the system path. I've manually added the locations of `protoc` and `grpc_cpp_plugin` to the Path.

It's not clear to me which file it is failing to find, there were some syntax errors picked up earlier in `test_interface.proto` So I know this file is being opened okay. I can also run `grpc_cpp_plugin` from the command line without any problems.

Does anyone know why this is failing to build the client and server code?

Answer (score 2):

make sure to add .exe to your plugin path like so: `C:\vcpkg\packages\grpc_x64-windows\tools\grpc\grpc_cpp_plugin.exe`

There's a note about this in our docs here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin